# Expected Value Game of Boxes

Tags: probability

There are 100 boxes each containing a dollar bill.  Every turn you open a random box and take the bill, unless the box is already empty – the bills are not replaced.  You play this game for 50 turns.

(a)  How likely is that a given box will be opened at least once during a game?

(b)  What is your expected win?

Comment: I think question (a) is 1/2.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  How much progress have you made?

Comment: Why would you think that?  Please also supply your reasoning.

Comment: Hint : Use the binomial distribution

Comment: I think question (a) is 1/2. Let X represent a given box so P(x) = 1/100 + 1/100 + ... + 1/100 which is the probability that we select box x in the first try, or in the second until 50 trials. P(X) = 50/100 = 1/2

Comment: So, if there game were played $200$ times, the probability that a given box was selected would be $2?$  This can't be right.

Comment: Hint: It will be easier to look at the complement.  How likely is it that the particular box will *not* be openned in fifty turns?

Comment: P(X != k) = (99/100)^50

Comment: So P(X = k) = 1 - P(X != k) = 1 - (99/100)^50 = 0.39499

Comment: @Desmoz Multiply by 100.  We've computed the expected return from a given *box* not a given *turn.*

Comment: A variant on this would be to stop after the first empty box (and allow up to $100$ attempts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for part $b$,your earning, $X$ is equal to the number of boxes that is opened at least once.

Use part $a$ and indicator variable

Write $$X= \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$$

for some indicator variable, then we have $$E[X]= \sum_{i=1}^{100} E[X_i]$$

Comment: E[X] = 100 • 0.39499 = $39.499

Comment: congratulations.

Comment: $1-.99^{50} = 0.3949939.$

Comment: In R:`u = replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(1:100, 50,rep=T)))); mean(u)` returns 39.49961 with margin of simulation error $\approx\pm$0.005.$

Comment: @BruceET always impressed with your simulations. =)